# c3.js how to update x-axis labels on chart.load()?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have a c3.js timeseries plot that is updated in response to some form elements via an API call using jQuery's `$.getJSON()`.  The data returned from the API call looks like:

```
     {
        "x-axis": ["2016-09-01", "2016-09-02", "2016-09-03", "2016-09-04", "2016-09-05", "2016-09-06", "2016-09-07", "2016-09-08", "2016-09-09", "2016-09-10", "2016-09-11", "2016-09-12", "2016-09-13", "2016-09-14", "2016-09-15", "2016-09-16", "2016-09-17", "2016-09-18", "2016-09-19", "2016-09-20", "2016-09-21", "2016-09-22", "2016-09-23", "2016-09-24", "2016-09-25", "2016-09-26", "2016-09-27", "2016-09-28", "2016-09-29", "2016-09-30"], 
        "Label 1": [35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0], 
        "Label 2": [124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0, 124.0]
     }
```

The plot is created like so:

```
        ts = c3.generate({
            bindto: "#timeseries",
            data: {
                x: "x-axis",
                json: data
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: "timeseries",
                    tick: {
                        format: function(x) {
                            return ts_date_format(x);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

One of the options allows switching from daily view (one plot point per-day for each label for one month) to a monthly view (one plot point per month for each label for one year), upon which a new API request is made, returning new values for "x-axis":

```
    {
        "x-axis": ["2015-10-01", "2015-11-01", "2015-12-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01", "2016-06-01", "2016-07-01", "2016-08-01", "2016-09-01"],
        "Label 1": [2854.0, 4509.0, 5895.0, 6932.0, 4143.0, 3076.0, 1880.0, 1454.0, 1098.0, 1016.0, 1004.0, 1048.0],
        "Label 2": [8680.0, 15090.0, 25079.0, 23746.0, 18096.0, 16058.0, 17610.0, 9269.0, 2550.0, 2852.0, 2232.0, 3720.0]
    }
```

The data is loaded fine, like so:

```
        ts.load({
            unload: true,
            json: data
        });
```

But the x axis of the plot is not updated to use the new "x-axis" values returned. The existing daily view values are reformatted into the monthly format by the `ts_date_format()` function referenced above.

http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-x looks promising, and it actually does work, sometimes.  This:

```
        ts.x(data["x-axis"]);
        ts.load({
            unload: true,
            json: data
        });
```

does in fact update the x axis values, but raises a large number of the d3 error `<rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN"`.  Reversing the order of the calls to `load()` and `x()` does not work, however, and does not raise an error:

```
        ts.load({
            unload: true,
            json: data
        });
        ts.x(data["x-axis"]);
```

The `axes` argument to `load()` also seems like it might be appropriate http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load, the docs say:

```
If axes given, the axes specifed by data.axes will be updated. axes must be Object that has target id as keys.
```

but that is a bit unclear to me.  I've tried lots of variations similar to:

```
        ts.load({
            unload: true,
            json: data,
            axes: {
                "x": data["x-axis"]
            }
        });
```

and

```
        data["axes"] = {
            "x": data["x-axis"]
        }
        ts.load({
            unload: true,
            json: data,
            axes: {
                "x": true
            }
        });
```

but they all fail to update the x axis values.

I am using c3.js version 0.4.11

**solution**

Thanks to duderoot below, I found the solution:

```
        var cols = [];
        for (var k in data) {
            cols.push([k].concat(data[k]));
        }
        ts.load({
            columns: cols
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I just remember that I recently played with this so here is a JSFiddle that do what you want.
https://jsfiddle.net/duderoot/vwwod780/
here is the function that I use to update the x lables

```
setTimeout(function () {
  chart.load({
    columns: [
        ["x", "2015-10-01", "2015-11-01", "2015-12-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01"],
        ["Label 1", 2854.0, 4509.0, 5895.0, 6932.0, 4143.0, 3076.0, 1880.0, 1454.0, 1098.0, 1016.0, 1004.0, 1048.0],
        ["Label 2", 8680.0, 15090.0, 25079.0, 23746.0, 18096.0, 16058.0, 17610.0, 9269.0, 2550.0, 2852.0, 2232.0, 3720.0]  
     ]
  });
}, 3000);
```

Hope it helps,
cheers

Comment: Thanks duderoot, works perfectly.  I had completely overlooked the columns keyword in the docs